# SQL Server GROUP BY too slow

Tags: sql, sql-server, performance, group-by, localdb

I'm trying to run two queries on SQL LocalDB. One of them executes fast and the other takes 12 seconds although the difference is only one column added to the select and group by clauses.

The following query executes in nearly no time:

```
select  [Company]
    ,sum([Hours]) as [Hours] 
from [Operation View]  
where company_id in (19,53,76,1) 
    and action_id in (5,21,23,30) 
    and [Report Date] >= '2014-04-01' 
group by [Company] 
order by Company
```

While the below query takes around 12 seconds:

```
select  [Company]
    ,Department
    ,sum([Hours]) as [Hours]
from [Operation View]  
where company_id in (19,53,76,1) 
    and action_id in (5,21,23,30) 
    and [Report Date] >= '2014-04-01' 
group by [Company]
    ,Department
```

As you can see, I only added one extra column `Department` in the select and group by clauses.

If I try to add more columns, the execution time remains at 12 seconds.

Is this a normal behavior? Is there anything I can do to speed up the query?

Note that the [Operation View] is a view that is based on a main table joined by other lookup tables that provides the link between the ID's and the Names of the fields.

I thought about indexing the view but I have a text column which prevented this option.

Comment: Create a composite index on `Company` **and** `Department`.

Comment: Tim - do you mean to create indexes in the underlying table? I can't create them in the view.

Comment: The first question remains: does it make sense that only by adding one column to the query, the execution time increases by 12 secs? And then adding more columns does not affect the time? Something doesn't sound correct to me..

Comment: Perhaps `Company` benefits from an index, but if you add another column (or more) this index doesn't help anymore.

Comment: We don't know that view. It may be that without the department there is a table less to scan, so it may be perfectly acceptable for the second query to take much longer.

Comment: Actually that's true.. the departments are stored in another lookup table (same as the companies)..

Comment: Here are some updates: I ran the same query with only grouping by Departments and it takes 12 secs. I tried with another column alone and it took the same time.. So it seems that only the Company column is fast and adding any other column causes the query to slow down. However, there's really no difference in the structure between the different columns... They are all similarly linked to lookup tables.

Comment: I also tried to create another indexed view (by removing the text column) and created an index on the (Company, Department) combination .. The query time is still the same.

Comment: This sounds like a great case of why you should select the data, then compute in LINQ. SQL sucks at doing computations!

Comment: @theMayer you are the kind of programmer that keeps me in a job

Comment: Well, I am hiring as a matter of fact 

Answer (score 0):

Since you can't create an index on the VIEW, I would hope the underlying tables have indexes to optimize the query, such as a compound index of ( company_id, action_id, report_date ).

That said, your group by condition appears based the company name and not the ID.  It MIGHT help if the group by was based on the company_ID instead of company -- IF the company names are completely different per their corresponding IDs, such as

```
id  company   Dept
1   Comp A    Dept X
2   Comp B    Dept Y
3   Comp C    Dept X
```

vs

```
id  company   Dept
1   Comp A    Dept X
2   Comp A    Dept Y
3   Comp A    Dept Z
```

in the second case, the ID group would not work as there could be many IDs with the same company name you would want grouped together and thus the actual name WOULD be the correct basis for grouping.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The reason I'm using the names in group by is that I need to show the company name in the end and not the ID as this query will be displayed to the end user. If I add "company" in the select clause, I have to add it to the group by.. otherwise I'll get an error.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you below approaches to solve the performance problem:

1. Try to create a composite non-clustered index on Company, Department in the base table of the view, to give good performance for GROUP BY.
2. As you are not able to create index on the view, try to create one more view which is having the columns: Company, Department, company_id, action_id, report_Date, with GROUP BY applied already and it should be possible for you index this view, as it is straightforward view. Just query the view with filters applied.